# playOrm - debug/run - TestManyToOne.java @ Refresh/Clean

Tags: java, eclipse, playorm

As suggested, drilling down into the test case, TestManyToOne.java and running/debuging readWriteBasic(NoSqlEntityManager)

Once refreshing and clearing up the project, I could succesfully run/debug the reWriteBasic Method.

Stepping through many, many, .... I finally completed the methhod debug.

**I did notice on several instances;**

```
Class<T>(Object).equals(Object) line: 134
```

showed up stating: "Source not found." and a button with "Edit Source Lookup Path..."

[image: ScreenShot Line 138 No SRC]

**Also noticed on a few occasions was;**

```
DboColumnMeta.getStorageType(Class) line: 199
```

Highlighting the "Name/Value" within the Variable view.

[image: Line199 VariableView Name/Value]

DECIMAL - 196 
INTEGER - 199 
STRING - 126 
INTEGER - 142 
etc.

- Is the preceding information what I am supposed to be seeing?
- I must of hit 'step into" 1000x, is that correct?
- Is Line 134 correct?
- The highlighting in the variables window?
- The console only shows a completion of the method running, what am I looking for???

Thanks ahead of time for any insights and/or advice,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on other questions I have seen from you, you are looking to learn how to "use" playOrm not learn how playOrm works, correct?????

If I am correct, you are stepping way too deep, way way too deep.  You should only stay in the 3 classes TestManyToOne.java, Activity.java and Account.java if you want to get a feel for how playOrm works.

Dean